# Is there an existing alphabetized list widget for jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am looking to create this common (on iPhone) list type using jQuery Mobile:

[image]

The key feature is the alphabet running down the right side that will scroll to the closest matching item.

Does something like this already exist or do I need to roll my own? I was unable to find it in the demos, although [List dividers](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc2/docs/lists/lists-divider.html) gets me part way there.

Comment: Roll your own. releated: http://jsfiddle.net/stodolaj/De8Ku/

Comment: @Phill: It is not sorting the data that is the issue, it is rendering the layout with the alphabet down the side which seems to overlay the content, and can scroll to the appropriate place when you select a letter.

Comment: I haven't seen that yet but they do offer a filtered list option: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc2/docs/lists/lists-search-with-dividers.html so typing the name filters the list

Comment: This would be a nice plugin to offer though +1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well it's a work in progress, but I think it can be done. example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/qXT9Z/32/

CSS

```
#list-navigation {
    color:#696969;

    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
    top:0px;
    z-index:200;
}
```

JS

```
$('.scrollToSelected').bind('click', function() {
    var view = $(this).attr('id');
    var list = view.split('-');
    var elem = $("#"+list[1]);

    // not sure if this is offset or position
    var position = elem.position(); 
    var offset   = elem.offset();

    //alert('left: '+position.left + ", top: " + position.top);
    //alert('left: '+offset.left + ", top: " + offset.top);

    $.mobile.silentScroll(position.top);
    //$.mobile.silentScroll(offset.top);

});

$('.showDetails').bind('click', function() {
    $.mobile.changePage( "#details", { transition: "slideup"} );
});
```

HTML

```
<div data-role="page" id="list">
    <div data-role="content">

        <ul data-role="listview">
            <li data-role="list-divider" id="a">A</li>
            <li class="showDetails">
                Adam Kinkaid
            </li>
            <li class="showDetails">Alex Wickerham</li>
            <li class="showDetails">Avery Johnson</li>
            <li data-role="list-divider" id="b">B</li>
            <li class="showDetails">Bob Cabot</li>
            <li data-role="list-divider" id="c">C</li>
            <li class="showDetails">Caleb Booth</li>
            <li class="showDetails">Christopher Adams</li>
            <li class="showDetails">Culver James</li>
            <li data-role="list-divider" id="d">D</li>
            <li class="showDetails">David Walsh</li>
            <li class="showDetails">Drake Alfred</li>
            <li data-role="list-divider" id="e">E</li>
            <li class="showDetails">Elizabeth Bacon</li>
            <li class="showDetails">Emery Parker</li>
            <li class="showDetails">Enid Voldon</li>
            <li data-role="list-divider" id="f">F</li>
            <li class="showDetails">Francis Wall</li>
            <li data-role="list-divider" id="g">G</li>
            <li class="showDetails">Graham Smith</li>
            <li class="showDetails">Greta Peete</li>
            <li data-role="list-divider" id="h">H</li>
            <li class="showDetails">Harvey Walls</li>
            <li data-role="list-divider" id="m">M</li>
            <li class="showDetails">Mike Farnsworth</li>
            <li class="showDetails">Murray Vanderbuilt</li>
            <li data-role="list-divider" id="n">N</li>
            <li class="showDetails">Nathan Williams</li>
            <li data-role="list-divider" id="p">P</li>
            <li class="showDetails">Paul Baker</li>
            <li class="showDetails">Pete Mason</li>
            <li data-role="list-divider" id="r">R</li>
            <li class="showDetails">Rod Tarker</li>
            <li data-role="list-divider" id="s">S</li>
            <li class="showDetails">Sawyer Wakefield</li>
        </ul>

        <ul data-role="none" id="list-navigation">
            <li>
                <p id="list-1" class="scrollToSelected"><strong>1</strong></p>
                <p id="list-2" class="scrollToSelected"><strong>2</strong></p>
                <p id="list-3" class="scrollToSelected"><strong>3</strong></p>
                <p id="list-a" class="scrollToSelected"><strong>A</strong></p>
                <p id="list-b" class="scrollToSelected"><strong>B</strong></p>
                <p id="list-c" class="scrollToSelected"><strong>C</strong></p>
                <p id="list-d" class="scrollToSelected"><strong>D</strong></p>
                <p id="list-e" class="scrollToSelected"><strong>E</strong></p>
                <p id="list-f" class="scrollToSelected"><strong>F</strong></p>
                <p id="list-g" class="scrollToSelected"><strong>G</strong></p>
                <p id="list-h" class="scrollToSelected"><strong>H</strong></p>
                <p id="list-i" class="scrollToSelected"><strong>I</strong></p>
                <p id="list-j" class="scrollToSelected"><strong>J</strong></p>
                <p id="list-k" class="scrollToSelected"><strong>K</strong></p>
                <p id="list-l" class="scrollToSelected"><strong>L</strong></p>
                <p id="list-m" class="scrollToSelected"><strong>M</strong></p>
                <p id="list-n" class="scrollToSelected"><strong>N</strong></p>
                <p id="list-o" class="scrollToSelected"><strong>O</strong></p>
                <p id="list-p" class="scrollToSelected"><strong>P</strong></p>
                <p id="list-q" class="scrollToSelected"><strong>Q</strong></p>
                <p id="list-r" class="scrollToSelected"><strong>R</strong></p>
                <p id="list-s" class="scrollToSelected"><strong>S</strong></p>
                <p id="list-t" class="scrollToSelected"><strong>T</strong></p>
                <p id="list-u" class="scrollToSelected"><strong>U</strong></p>
                <p id="list-v" class="scrollToSelected"><strong>V</strong></p>
                <p id="list-w" class="scrollToSelected"><strong>W</strong></p>
                <p id="list-x" class="scrollToSelected"><strong>X</strong></p>
                <p id="list-y" class="scrollToSelected"><strong>Y</strong></p>
                <p id="list-z" class="scrollToSelected"><strong>Z</strong></p>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="details">
    <div data-role="content">

        <ul data-role="listview">
            <li data-role="list-divider">Details</li>
            <li><a href="#list" data-direction="reverse">List</a></li>
        </ul>
        <br />
        <p>
            Here are the details you were looking for
        </p>

    </div>
</div>
```