# Phonegap contact list with alphabetical quick scroll?

Tags: html, css, cordova

I'm implementing a contact list in a Phonegap iOS app and was wondering how to best implement an alphabetical quick scroll? Thank you!  (see the right side of the screenshot below)

[image: iosscroll]

Comment: Amy I am trying to implement the same feature in my phonegap application, but is unable to implement this feature successfully.Will you please tell me details how you successfully implemented this ? It will be really helpful to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple calls this feature 'section index navigation' of an iOS UITableView [1].

Here are some CSS/HTML/JS Implementations:
-SenchaTouch has a really nice implementation. Demo at [2] under "grouped" list.
-Some jsfiddles posted in response to another SO question [3].
-Another implementation (demo doesn't appear to work though) [4].

[[1]](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
[[2]](http://cdn.sencha.io/touch/sencha-touch-2.1.0/examples/kitchensink/index.html#demo/list) [[3]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7933063/is-there-an-existing-alphabetized-list-widget-for-jquery-mobile)
[[4]](http://cubiq.org/contact-list-on-webkit-for-iphone)